# ERROR converting from JSONArray to JSONObject processing Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I'm having difficult with an error I keep getting when trying to process my JSON.
Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject is an error I keep getting and I don't know whats causing it.
The JSON is:

```
{
   "recipe":[
      {
         "recipeID":"1",
         "recipeName":"chicken salad",
         "ingredients":"chicken lettuce tomato cucumber"
      },
      {
         "recipeID":"2",
         "recipeName":"banana shake",
         "ingredients":"banana ice cream vanilla "
      }
   ]
}
```

And what I'm doing to process it is:

```
  JSONArray recipes = null;

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                recipes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("recipe");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // looping through All recipes
                for (int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = recipes.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = c.getString("recipeName");
}
```

But I keep getting this error :/

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Comment: How is your "json" string defined? Are you using JSONParser?

Comment: @tinuviel Hi, androidstudio points the error at this line: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: @miselking the json is returned from php as a string from url request
I'm new to android sorry guys for poor knowledge :(

Comment: @Lakhvir: means getting JSONArray instead of JSONObject  from server

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK so how do I process it in order to extract the values? :S

Comment: @Lakhvir: show real string which getting from server. or try as `JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);Log.i("TAG","jsonArray : "_jsonArray.toString());` and post jsonArray string with question

Comment: Try printing out the json string to make sure that it's an expected value

Answer (score 0):

I see you are parsing the Json string by hand, you can do it, and it is quickly enough, but in my case I always use some type of library that do the job for me, so I will like to recommend you that take a look at Gson library from google.
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/